# Does anyone know how to write a file using Swift Script?

Tags: swift

I am currently trying to write a script with Swift.
In the first run, the content was not written to the file.
But the second time it worked the same way.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

This is the code I wrote now.

```swift
func write_code_in_file(_ file_path: String,_ codes: String) {
    let write_code = Process()
    write_code.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/env")
    write_code.arguments = ["touch", current_path+file_path]
    
    do {
        try write_code.run()
    } catch {
        print("⚠️ Error - write code in file")
    }
    
    if let data: Data = codes.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) { // String to Data
        do {
            try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: current_path + file_path))
        } catch let e {
            print("⚠️"+e.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And the result value when you run it.

[image]

Comment: What are the values of `current_path + file_path` and `codes`?

Comment: The `current_path` is the Root portion, and the `file_path` is the current location of the file.

Comment: When you use and run a Process task it is executed as a sub-process so most likely the code after run() is executed before the sub-process is finished. Why do you even need to use Process here?

Comment: I used the Process instance to execute other commands within the script.

It hasn't been long since I studied Process instances, so I might be inexperienced...